# Using Eco and CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, docpad, eco

How can I use If statement to specific a variable that is defined in the docpad.coffee file.

I want to do something like this:

```
<% if sponsor.type == 'Gold': %>
<li class="sponsor-item gold" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <a href="<%= sponsor.url %>" class="sponsor-logo sponsor-link" itemprop="url">
    <img src="<%= sponsor.logo %>" alt="<%= sponsor.name %>" class="photo" itemprop="image">
  </a>
<% else: %>
<li class="sponsor-item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <a href="<%= sponsor.url %>" class="sponsor-logo sponsor-link" itemprop="url">
    <img src="<%= sponsor.logo %>" alt="<%= sponsor.name %>" class="photo" itemprop="image">
  </a>
<% end %>
```

This is a code I've made, but he find the string but doesn't add the class "gold" (defined in the li) in the gold sponsor type.

Answer (score 0):

To get variables defined in your template data you must prefix them with the `@` character, like so `@sponsor` -> this translates to `this.sponsor` in javascript.

This is because template data variables are assigned to the this scope in eco. You can read more about this here: https://github.com/sstephenson/eco#the-context-object